# AsyncTask doInBackground does not execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I tried almost all the solution but there's some problem with my Inner AsyncTask class. It seems that `doInBackground()` is not being executed.

`onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()`are working. However, `doInBackground()` does not read the code.

I'm really sure about getJSON() is correct 100% because i used the same code before

this is my class

```
public class My extends Activity implements Runnable {
    public static String s = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            findViewById(android.R.id.content).postDelayed(this, 3000);
            getJSON("My link ");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
 private void getJSON(String url) {

    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String uri = params[0];

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    sb.append(json+"\n");
                }

                s = sb.toString().trim();

                return sb.toString().trim();

            } catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String ss) {
            super.onPostExecute(ss);
            s = ss;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute(url);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If onPreExecute and onPostExecute are working, I believe that doInBackground is also working... Did you  try to insert some log message and check where the code is probably failing? Your try/catch does not print any log in case of exception etc... Add some logs and made some tests....

Comment: Did you add internet permission to your manifest? Did you run in debug checking if any exception is thrown? My best bet is that you are returning null with the exception

Comment: I debugged the program step by step it didnt enroll to doInBackground  at all 

and i used the same AsyncTask code in the same project (another class ) its work

Comment: Calling `super.onPreExecute()` and `super.onPostExecute()` is pointless.

Comment: Are you sure your `onPostExecute()` method is called before you move to the next activity? If yes, what's the value of variable `s`?

Comment: when i debugged i look at it and it still null No change

Comment: Assign a dummy value to `s` instead of `null` in the beginning. And check whether you get the same in `onPostExecute` or `null`. If it's `null`, it means your `doInBackground()` caught an exception and hence returned `null`.

Comment: Try removing the finish(); in the runnable

Comment: @Seaskyways no that not related to the problem at all

Comment: @PrerakSola   yes  Good point I didnt mention to this before .but until now i didnt understand why the debug didnt enroll to the code 
even if there is an error exception . 
there was an error from the url because that i got null  but I didnt get any step inside the catch when i'm debug the program
thank you

Comment: @fedepaol thank you for your point too :)

Comment: Put a break point in your catch statement. Or put a log before your "return null" and see if it is getting printed.